# Parse Unity WebGL - SignUpAsync Task Not Completing

Tags: parse-platform, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I'm having trouble signing up users through Parse in my Unity app. In the editor, everything works as expected, but once I build it to the WebGL platform, I have a problem.

When I call `SignUpAsync()` on a user, it is correctly setting up the user as intended on the Parse server and also sending the user email verifications (because I have it set to do so), however the actual task from the app does not receive any callback from Parse about its completion. In other words, `task.IsCompleted` is never set to true, no matter how long I wait. No errors are being thrown, and if I attempt to log in with the same credentials afterwards, it works. But there is still no way for the app to know that it's done signing up.

I don't know if this is a bug with Parse or its connection to WebGL, or if it's somewhere on my server. Does anyone have any ideas for things to check?

Answer (score 0):

Parse's Unity SDK does not support WebGL since WebGL does not support threading and tasks.

I've been searching for a solution and found reference to people who say they have either grabbed the open source parse SDK and replaced tasks with coroutines OR swapped out the Unity SDK for the RESTful API.

Hope that helps point you in the right direction.